# Defined new theorem (amsthm) and new environment (Environ). Document won't compile if I use theorem inside environment. How can I fix this?

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm, newtheorem

As the title says, I have defined a new theorem (`example`) and a new environment (`revision`). they both work fine, but if I use the theorem inside the environment I get the following errors (copied directly from the quickfix list in vim):

```
test.tex|27 error| LaTeX Error: \begin{example} on input line 27 ended by \end{revision}.
test.tex|27 error| Undefined control sequence.
test.tex|27 error| Undefined control sequence.
test.tex|29 error| LaTeX Error: \begin{revision} on input line 20 ended by \end{document}.
test.tex|29 error| Improper \prevdepth.
test.tex|29 error| Missing } inserted.
test.tex|29 error| Missing } inserted.
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}

\title{Title}
\author{}
\date{}


\newtheorem{example}{}

\NewEnviron{revision}{\expandafter\uline\expandafter{\BODY}}


\begin{document}

\begin{revision}

    \begin{example}
    some example text
    \end{example}


\end{revision}

\end{document}
```

I include the original `{\expandafter\uline\expandafter{\BODY}}` for the `revision` environment because if I try to do a minimal example with the very bare minimum, then the document compiles successfully without errors, but the resulting PDF is only  single page with a page number (example code below). But this isn't a MWE of my problem, because in my problem I do have the errors above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}

\title{Title}
\author{}
\date{}


\newtheorem{example}{}

\NewEnviron{revision}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{revision}

    \begin{example}
    some example text
    \end{example}


\end{revision}

\end{document}
```

I'm not really sure where to start to solve this, any help appreciated!

Comment: \uline is like \soul: it doesn't like arbitrary content. You can't put a complete theorem in its argument.

Comment: you could see this question is unrelated to the environment definition just have `\uline{\begin{example}.....\end{example}}` and you will see essentially the same error message.